# Find a counter example for the convergence of a sequence that has a property close from cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to find a counter example for this statement : Let ($x_n$) be a sequence such as $\forall m > 0, 
lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (x_{n+m} -x_n) = 0$, also ($x_n$) is bounded. Then the sequence $(x_n)$ converges.

I think that the statement is false so I tried to find a counter example.I tried with cosinus , sinus , tangent but each time there is a problem.  Maybe something with the logarithmic function can work ? But I assume this function is nothing usual and need a complex construction.

Can you help me find it please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_n=\sin(2\pi \ln(n))$. Recall that $|\sin(a)-\sin(b)| \le |a-b|$, so $\forall m \in \Bbb{N}$ $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}|x_{n+m}-x_n| \le \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}|2\pi \ln(n+m)-2\pi \ln(n)|=2\pi \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}|\ln(1+\frac{m}{n})|=0$$ and $\{x_n\}$ does not converge(this derives from the fact that $y_n=\{\ln(n)\}$ is dense in $[0,1]$).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!  @Zerox

Comment: @chloe2107 Proving that $\{x_n\}$ does not converge is somewhat hard.

Comment: You can do it by finding 2 sub sequences that have different limits ?

Comment: @chloe2107 I update the answer and I hope the divergence is easier for you to prove.

Answer (score 0):

Another argument for not convergence of sin(ln(n)) would be to note that ln(n) is dense on [0,1] mod 1. This is easy to see since ln(n+1) - ln(n) tends to 0 monotonically.
Lastly, since sin(x) is continuous sin(ln(n)) is dense in [0,sin1].